# How to insert a sql query(select statement with user input) inside a table

Tags: sql, insert

How can I insert a select query inside a column. This sql query requires a user input from the screen.

For example:

I have a table with 2 columns: `Query_ID_fruit`, `SQL_QUERY_COL_FRUIT`

```
select fruitA from fruits where fruitAttribute = '&fruitAttribute';
```

how can I insert the sql query above in `SQL_QUERY_COL_FRUIT`?

Comment: It's text, it should be simple.  What sort of difficulty are you having?

Comment: Is this query going to return one or multiple records ?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
INSERT INTO fruits_querys (SQL_QUERY_COL_FRUIT)
VALUES ("select fruitA from fruits where fruitAttribute = '&fruitAttribute';");
```

Comment: Double quotes will cause a syntax error on every database engine with which I work.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the result of *any* `select` clause into a table. If your `select` returns the same number of columns of your destination table (and in the same order), you can use:

```
insert into your_destination_table
select ...
```

If you need to insert into your destination table but you are not going to fill all the columns, or the select has the columns in different order:

```
insert into your_destination_table (field1, field2, ...)
select ...
```

Of course you need to fulfill any conditions the destination table has (e.g.: no null values on PK fields, the data types of your select must match the data types of the columns of your destination table, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Be very, very, careful when inserting SQL queries into a table. If they are built using user input you can very easily have a SQL injection vulnerability.  Try to use parameterized queries or at least escape any user input before inserting the SQL query into the table.

To escape single quotes you actually use two back to back, so '' inside a string turns into '.

For your query you can use:

```
'select fruitA from fruits where fruitAttribute = ''&fruitAttribute'';'
```

which should work. Just be careful of what `&fruitAttribute` is.